# Cardinalities and injective function between two infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A$ and $B$ two infinite sets and let $|A| = m$ and $|B| = n$ and also suppose that $m > n$. Also suppose that $g$ is an injective function from $B$ into $A$. For each of the following sets, find its cardinality $(m, n, 2^m \mbox{ or } 2^n)$ and prove your answer.

1) $S_{1} = \{f\in B^A : |f(A)| = 1 \}$.

2) $S_{2} = \{ f\in B^A : |f(A)| = 2 \}$.

3) $S_{3} = A - g(B) $

I am trying to solve this exercise but i seem to struggle a lot on proving the cardinality of the above sets.

Comment: For each of *which* following sets?

Comment: I just added the sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  The first one asks how many functions from $A$ to $B$ there are where every element of $A$ is mapped to the same element of $B$.  That is what $|f(A)|=1$ means.  How many functions like that are there?  The second asks how many functions from $A$ to $B$ there are where every element of $A$ is mapped to one of two elements of $B$.  How is this different from $S_1?$  What do you think $S_3$ means?

Comment: Thank you for your response. We know that in general, each element in $A$ has $n$ choices to be mapped to $B$, where each choice is a function. So the total number of functions from $A$ to $B$ is $n^m$. So for the first one there exist $n$ functions. Is that right? Now, for the second one, are there $2^m$? but how can I prove that?

Comment: You are right for the first.  For the second, you first have to choose the two elements of $B$  that are the image, then you choose which one each element of $A$ goes to.  Yes, you should wind up with $2^m,$ but you need to show that by a chain of reasoning to show the choices of elements in $B$ don't matter.  If $B$ were  larger than $2^m$ the argument would fail.

Comment: I don not seem to understand your argument on how to prove this. My thought is that there are $2^m$ functions from $A$ to $B$ mapping 2 or less $b_{0} \in B$. But these functions include the ones that map only one element of $B$.So the there are $2^m - m$ functions with this property. Which part of this is wrong?

Comment: @Angela your arguments seem to more or less ignore the fact that we are dealing with infinite sets. What does it mean for a set to have $2^m-m$ elements if $m$ is an infinite cardinal?

Comment: Yes!You are right!So, in order to prove the second one, we need to map a 2 element set $B$ to a $m$ element set $A$. We can do that by $2^m$ different ways, all beginning with two elements, 1 and 2. This is just a different combination of mappings over $B$. Is that right? Also, in the last set, are we looking for the non surjective functions?

Comment: Be more careful with your wording.  We are mapping the $m$ element set $A$ to a two element  subset of $B$, which we can do in $2^m$ ways.  If the sets were finite, you would have more choices because of selecting the two elements of $B$, but with $n \lt m$ that doesn't increase the number.  That is a big part of the argument you are supposed to make.  For the last part, there is just one function $g$.  You are supposed to count the elements of $A$ that are left after we delete the range of $g$

Comment: Ok, since the set $A$ is infinite, then by deleting some elements, it would still be infinite and so the cardinality of $S_3$ is $m$. Is that true?

Comment: That is true because you are given that $m \gt n$.  If $|A|$ were $n$ we couldn't tell.  It could be $0$, it  could be $n$, it could be anywhere in between.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!